# Freebase MQL query to retrieve country description by alpha 3 code

Tags: google-api, freebase, mql

I have been trying to come up with the appropriate MQL query to retrieve country description like how the text api does it.

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/en/jamaica

**result from that call.**

> "result": "Jamaica (/dʒəˈmeɪkə/), officially the Commonwealth of Jamaica, is an island nation of the Greater Antilles, 234 kilometres (145 mi) in length, up to 80 kilometres (50 mi) in width, and 10,990 square kilometres (4,240 sq mi) in area.

I cant use the text/ topic api because I need to gather this information using the alpha 2/ alpha 3 code. This is my attempt at making the query.

> [{
>     "id": null,
>     "name": null,
>     "/common/topic/description": null,
>     "type": "/location/country",
>     "/location/country/iso_alpha_3": "USA"
>   }]

When I run this query the common/topic/description field is not being populated.
Is there any other way to retrieve a description of the country and filter by the alpha code 3?

Comment: Did you really get the description for Jamaica back when using Cuba's ID?

Comment: oh No I didnt lol sorry...let me change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [Freebase Topic API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/topic-overview):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/authority/iso/3166-1/alpha-3/JAM?filter=/common/topic/description
```

Please make sure that you give proper attribution to the source as specified in the API response.

Comment: Thanks so much Shawn, I have been trying for hours to figure this out. Is there a way to construct a MQL query to do the same?

Comment: No, MQL queries don't provide topic descriptions. The best way to do it is with the Topic API because that one provides the correct attribution.

Answer (score 1):

The ISO country codes are registered in namespaces rooted at /authority and those identifiers can be used interchangeably with identifiers from the /en or /m namespaces.  Just substitute the appropriate ID into your Text API call e.g.

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/authority/iso/3166-1/alpha-3/USA